# Loading .qss theme from qrc file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use the [qdarkstyle](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet) theme.
Ive followed the code but I cant seem to load the stylesheet.  Here is how i'm loading the code in main.cpp:

```
QFile f(":qdarkstyle/style.qss");
if (!f.exists())
{
    printf("Unable to set stylesheet, file not found\n");
}
else
{
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QTextStream ts(&f);
    qApp->setStyleSheet(ts.readAll());
}
```

but exists() is always false.  The folder qdarkstyle is in the sub-directory of my main source

[image]

My project Resources looks like this:[image]

Ive tried the following calls:

```
QFile f(":qdarkstyle/style.qss");
QFile f("://qdarkstyle/style.qss");
QFile f(":/qdarkstyle/style/qdarkstyle/style.qss");
```

but I always exists is always false.  Any ideas on what i'm doing wrong

**Adding My .pro file**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MediaManagerV2
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc \
    qdarkstyle/style.qrc
```

**Link to source**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwXCsqWT3wkXV1dYNzF1dFM4dTQ/view?usp=sharing

**Fix**

Modified code

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

QFile f(":/qdarkstyle/style.qss");
if (!f.exists())
{
    printf("Unable to set stylesheet, file not found\n");
}
else
{
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);
    QTextStream ts(&f);
    a.setStyleSheet(ts.readAll());
}
```

basically moved show() above

Comment: You could show your .pro file.

Comment: You have added the .qrc file to your .pro:
`RESOURCES += 
    qdarkstyle/style.qrc`

Comment: Ive updated above and added my .pro file

Comment: I have tried it and I have not had problems, I could help if you share your project via github, dropbox or similar.

Comment: I was actually doing that.  Its just a new project so its very small.  Thanks

Comment: So I added a link to my post above to the code

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc for offering to look at my code.

Comment: see this: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/MediaManagerV2

Comment: Awesome will you change your comment so I can accept your comment as the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the `.qrc` file to your .pro:

```
RESOURCES += qdarkstyle/style.qrc
```

And move `show()` before calling the stylesheet.